# 'docker-compose up' inside project folder returns 'no such file or directory'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Whenever I run 'docker-compose up' from within my project folder, I get the following error, even though a valid docker-compose.yml file is present:

```
ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'./~/Projects/personal-docker-cluster/docker-compose.yml'
```

On the surface, something's adding an extra './' at the beginning of the path that shouldn't be necessary, and I'm pretty sure that's whats throwing it off here.

I've been able to get around this by using the -f flag, but it bugs me that I can't use a simple 'docker-compose up' to get going.

Could someone shed some light on what's going on here, and how to fix it?

edit:
Forgot to add versions and stuff:

```
# docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe

# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
```

Comment: could you show the exact command you execute and the path from which you execute it? it seems you call it with the path to the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: If possible, add your sample `docker-compose.yml` file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is gonna sound silly, but I found the solution to my problem so I'm posting it here for posterity.

Turns out the issue was that I had a COMPOSE_FILE environment variable set in my .bashrc, pointed to the same folder as in the error. I found it when I went to examine my .bashrc for a completely different issue, and I have no recollection of ever putting it there.

Removing it has fixed the problem completely.